# Mac suddenly not loading some web pages

Tags: network, wifi

Most websites (gmail, youtube, facebook, etc.) suddenly will no longer load on my mac, regardless of browser, when on my home network. However, some pages, like Amazon or soundcloud, still load perfectly fine. I'm able to load all pages perfectly on my phone using the same wifi network. When I run a hotspot, my mac can load all pages again. Here are some screenshots of my network settings/the error I receive:

[image: Loading error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason your network address range is set to a non-private address?

Comment: tell us about your home network WiFi signal hold Option key and click on WiFi icon, and report what you see

Comment: Can you add what is your Wi-Fi router? Is it protected with a strong password? Could you verify its own DNS servers?